# How build css for custom layout?

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table

I want to reproduce Google's spreadsheet behaviour with frozen first row and first col, in htmlm with little additions. This is done inside a web browser, so it's a site, page or web app (written in React, if that even matters, cuz question is mostly about css). Lets start with layout:

Availble view space of the page is separated in 3 distinct areas:

- 100% width, variable height Header, attached to top
- **Main View**, occupying space between header and footer
- 100% width, variable height Footer, attached to bottom

**Main View** is then gonna to be split into two sections:

- Menu of variable width, attached to the left-side
- **Table view**, occupying remaining width

And **Table view** should have following properties:

- Table area is scrollable, except
- First row, where table headers must remain always visible
- First column, where order No # of item must be always visible

I am stucked of a good and straightforward implementation. I gave up using `<table>` because it has no power to implement it, so clever `<div>` handling most probably would do the trick.

My question is **How to write css for that layout**? Lets omit layout html/jsx, I think its obvious. What css structure and classes would you suggest to me for this particular task?

Comment: Did you write any code for this and research open source systems? Here you can ask for help with coding and code structure architecture, but you should try it first. If you ask for a direct statement of opinion on a general issue, you will not get an answer and it will be against the rules.

Comment: Check here: https://medium.com/@vembarrajan/html-css-tricks-scroll-able-table-body-tbody-d23182ae0fbc

table header with `display: block;` and table body with `overflow: auto` seems to solve your problem

Comment: @ariferol01 Sure thing, I tried many different approaches with <table>+css, and just disliked them. There are too many code, I've erased and changed it alot. Task can be subdivided.. ok, I'll better update question body

Comment: @xakepp35 You can review js spreadsheet grid libraries at https://jspreadsheets.com Almost all open source spreadsheet libraries is available on this site. Maybe it might work

Comment: Have a look at CSS grid